# How to update one cell using the onChange Event from another cell?

Tags: javascript, datagrid, dojo

A simple template of dojo's Datagrid is as follows, I am building it for something much more complicated.

For example, how do I update field2's value based on the onChange event of field1 of the same row? Like copy field1's value to field2. The problem is I don't have the id of the particular cell, put onChange under layout or addRow() both doesn't seem right, and seems that onChange: function(){...} can't be used?

```
/*set up data store*/
var data = {
  identifier: "id",
  items: []
};


var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data: data});

/*set up layout*/
var layout = [
defaultCell: {
    editable: true,
    type: dojox.grid.cells._Widget
}
rows: [
    {name: 'ID', field: 'id', width: '30px', widgetClass: dijit.form.TextBox, editable: false},
{name: 'ColA', field: 'field1', width: '100px', widgetClass: dijit.form.TextBox},
{name: 'ColB', field: 'field2', width: '100px', widgetClass: dijit.form.TextBox}

]
];

/*create a new grid*/
var grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
    id: 'grid',
    store: store,
    structure: layout,
singleClickEdit: true,
    rowSelector: '15px'});

/*append the new grid to the div*/
grid.placeAt("gridDiv");

/*Call startup() to render the grid*/
grid.startup();


function addRow(){
    store.newItem({
    id: grid.rowCount,
    field1: '-',
    field2: '-'});
    grid.render();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `onApplyCellEditin(Value, inRowIndex, inFieldIndex)` instead.

Comment: onApplyCellEdit + intead of updating another grid field, it might be easier to simply update the store's value for the attribute you are looking for